# The logic not to use "*" for class that memory dynamically allocated

Tags: c++

so i'm learning c++ and i just learned about dynamically allocated memory for class. there's something that make me it feel weird.

```
int main()
{
    person* pOne = new person("mike", 35);
    cout << pOne << " " << pOne->getName() << endl;

    person pTwo = { "dave", 30 };
    cout << pTwo.getName() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

i think that when we want to call getName() function in pOne, we should do it like `*pOne->getName()` because pOne hold the memory location, not the person object itself. but if i do that i'll got compiler error.

i do it with `pTwo` that not dynamically allocated and it work like i tought.

so, can someone explain the logic of not using "*" when trying to call function?

Comment: FDuldul • This is a very insightful question (and Angew & Ivan have good answers).  The one extra bit of fun is a smart pointer like `std::unique_ptr` is an object, which has an `operator->`, which the `->` will be applied to every returned object until the returned type is a pointer, and then perform the pointer member access.  That is how a lot of the "magic" of C++ happens around `->`.  You don't get that magic with `(*a).b`.

Comment: @Angew • hmmm, how do you chained `operator*`?  I posted an example of chained `operator->` on question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48953206 , is there special syntax to get similar magic with overloaded `*`?  (Maybe I should post a new question.)

Comment: @Eljay Sorry, I must have misread the comment. I didn't notice the mention of chaining.

Comment: @Angew • ah, okay, nevermind.  :-)  I thought I might be missing some interesting (but not often used) dark corner feature of C++.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The built-in operator `a->b` is defined as `(*a).b`, so the dereference is "hidden" inside the `->` operator.

Answer (score 6):

`->` is just a syntactic sugar: `a->foo` is the same as `(*a).foo`. So when you use `->` you in fact dereference the pointer.

Answer (score 2):

> i do it with pTwo that not dynamically allocated and it work like i tought.
>   so, can someone explain the logic of not using "*" when trying to call function?

You mixed different concepts, it is not related how you allocated memory, but on which type of variable you access member:

```
struct Foo { void bar(); };

Foo f; // type of f is Foo
f.bar(); // access on type Foo is through .
Foo *pf = &f; // type of pf is Foo*
pf->bar(); // derefence and access on type Foo* is through ->
(*pf).bar(); // the same as above and since type of *pf is Foo we can use .
(&f)->bar(); // type of &f is Foo*, so we can use ->
(*(&f)).bar(); // crazy stuff
```

Answer (score 1):

It'll be clearer if you change the way you write your code.

Instead of:

```
person *pOne = new person("mike", 35);
```

Write:

```
person* pOne = new person("mike", 35);
```

This means the same to the compiler, but makes it clearer to humans that this is a `person*` (a pointer-to-`person`) called `pOne`.

Now it makes more sense that you still perform pointer operations on `pOne`, not on `*pOne`.

The older, right-aligned asterisks approach comes from the C world, in which people wanted you to think of it more like "there is a `person` at `*pOne`". And, in your case, that is true: **`(*pOne).getName()` would also have worked.** However, that looks pretty ugly to me, and `*pOne` isn't always an actual `person` — it depends on what (if anything) the pointer is set to.

**The key point here is that `->` (as in `pOne->getName()`) does that dereferencing for you.** Writing `(*pOne)->getName()` would be doing it twice.

Your final example of `pTwo.getName()` is just a bog-standard object access.

Comment: inb4 "you can't write your code like this because there is one edge case which you shouldn't be using anyway where it doesn't work"

Comment: or inb4 "the compiler sees it the first way therefore you must too (even though you are not a compiler)"

Comment: unfortunately `type* var` is against syntax rules so it can create another misunderstanding.

Comment: @Slava what syntax rules is it against? I prefer person* pOne because it fits more logically into how I think about pointers. Bottom line is that whichever one you choose just be consistent.

Comment: @noobcoder  "what syntax rules is it against?" - `int* p1, p2;` is misleading, as syntax rules bind * to variable, not type. I think best would be to create a type alias but that is usually too verbose.

Comment: @Slava correct, but I think that rule is what Lightness Races was talking about. Just because that edge case exists doesn't mean you have to stop coding a certain way. I just avoid that edge case by never declaring more then 1 var on a line, which I don't find as readable anyway.

Comment: @noobcoder it certainly would not stop you from using it, and I do not try to. Problem is I do not know if it is good to recommend to use such practice for a novice programmer, as he/she would not know what additional restriction it implies and probably would not have enough self discipline to follow it properly. So as I said such rule unfortunately conflicts with syntax of the language and of course it is too late to change it.