# How object of smart pointer object accessing member funtion of other class

Tags: c++, c++11

I have gone through the smart pointer implementation. In the below program:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Car{

public:
    void Run(){
        cout<<"Car Running..."<<"\n";
    }
};

class CarSP{

    Car * sp;

public:
    //Initialize Car pointer when Car 
    //object is createdy dynamically
    CarSP(Car * cptr):sp(cptr)
    {
    }

    // Smart pointer destructor that will de-allocate
    //The memory allocated by Car class.
    ~CarSP(){       
        printf("Deleting dynamically allocated car object\n");
        delete sp;
    }

    //Overload -> operator that will be used to 
    //call functions of class car
    Car* operator-> ()
    {    
        return sp;
    }
};


//Test
int main(){

    //Create car object and initialize to smart pointer
    CarSP ptr(new Car());
    ptr.Run();

    //Memory allocated for car will be deleted
    //Once it goes out of scope.
    return 0;
}
```

This program is working fine with:

```
CarSP ptr(new Car());
ptr->Run();
```

But `ptr` is not a pointer its object of the class `CarSP` Now my doubt is  how `->` is used for accessing Car member function with this. If i am using `ptr.Run();`
But its giving error,

Please help.

Comment: Note the `operator->` overload that returns a `Car*`.

Comment: Re, "//Initialize Car pointer when Car object is createdy dynamically"; Constructors and destructors are called for objects that are allocated on the stack or, in static variables too.

Comment: According to cppreference.com, "The overload of operator -> must either return a raw pointer or return an object (by reference or by value), for which operator -> is in turn overloaded. ". So it seems it will keep calling `operator->` on whatever you return until it gets to a raw pointer. In your case `Car::Run()` is called on the instance returned by `operator->`

Answer (score 0):

Since I cannot include a code example in a comment, I'm adding it here as an "answer", but this is not a proper answer.  See patatahooligan's link to the other Stack Overflow Q&A for a detailed explanation.

Here is a contrived example for illustrative purposes:

```
#include <iostream>

static char const* hello = "hello";

struct Foo
{
  char const* something() const { return hello; }
};
struct Bar
{
  Foo foo;
  Foo const* operator->() const { return &foo; }
};
struct Quux
{
  Bar bar;
  Bar const& operator->() const { return bar; }
};
struct Baz
{
  Quux quux;
  Quux const& operator->() const { return quux; }
};
struct Corge
{
  Baz baz;
  Baz const& operator->() const { return baz; }
};

int main()
{
  Corge corge;

  // The -> resolves to a Foo const*, then called something() method.
  char const* s = corge->something();

  std::cout << "Result is: " << s << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ptr->Run();
```

so C++ defines `a->b` to be `(*a).b` if and only if `a` is a pointer.

In this case, `ptr` is not a pointer.  When `a` is not a pointer, it defines it to be:

```
(ptr.operator->())->b
```

in this case, `ptr` is a class type that has an `operator->`.  That `operator->` returns a pointer to `Car`.

So we have

```
(some pointer to Car)->b
```

and we recursively apply the C++ rule for `->`.  And as a pointer to car can be `->Run()`'d, it works.